# Custom LINQ extension for make join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-extensions

Let's say I need create custom expression to make some manipulation with `IQueryable<x>` and `IQueryable<y>`. Regretfully I do not have idea how to implement this. This is my try:

```
public static IQueryable<T> JoinQueries<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IQueryable<T> expr)
        {
           if (query == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("query");
            //Here we make Join for x and and return result something like this:
           query = from a in query join b in expr on a.Id equals b.Id select a;
            return query;
        }
```

Or say other words I need result like this:

```
IQueryable <somevalue> x = query.CustomJoinExtension(Iqueryablevalue);
```

Comment: I would assume `expr` needs to be `Expression<Func< , >>`. In order to access `Id` you need to use a generic constraint `where T : SomeEntity`

Comment: You want to combine two different queries on the same type? Or did i misunderstand something?

Comment: @CallumLinington, thanks, may you provide some simple example please, I'm completele new to use extensions and expressions.

Comment: @BastiM, yes, this sound wrong that's why I'm asking how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> JoinQueries<T>
(this IQueryable<T> query, IQueryable<T> expr) where T : IHasId
{
    if (query == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("query");
    //Here we make Join for x and and return result something like this:
    query = from a in query join b in expr on a.Id equals b.Id select a;
    return query;
}

public interface IHasId
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: if this is for use in the Entity Framework, the class restriction should have "class" added, otherwise EF cannot understand the query: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21172754/1117815